# How to disable all events of MapControl?

Tags: bing-maps, windows-10, uwp, bing-api

Since my MapControl using only as preview of location, i want to disable zoom/pan and other events, is it possible to do?

Comment: Typically if you set [`IsHitTestVisible="false"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) then all interaction will be ignored. But @rbrundritt's answer is a good alternative.

Comment: I can say after test that this solution doesn't work at all on bing map control for UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much easier option would be to use the Bing Maps REST imagery service. It would use a lot less resources than loading up an interactive map control and disabling all events. It would also take a lot less work. You can find documentation on the Bing Maps REST imagery service here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx